# Flex: how to load a .swf and use its library?

Tags: apache-flex, swfloader

I have a symbol in a .swf's library, with a linkage name of "Pana". The Pana symbol is just a 100 frame animation that I would like to have timeline control over in Flex. So how can I load the .swf and then add the Pana symbol to the display list and control it's timeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the getDefinition function from the ApplicationDomain Class.  A fairly simple example can be found here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e07.html

Answer (score 0):

You can embed that symbol in your MXML:

```
[Embed(source="yourlib.swf#SymbolName")]
private var swfSymbol:Class;
```

And then use it as:

```
// Cast it as MovieClip
var symb:MovieClip = new swfSymbol() as MovieClip;
addChild(symb);
// And control the timeline
symb.gotoAndPlay('someFrameLabel');
```